# How does an array's equal method work?

Tags: java

Hey I'm currently studying for a java final and I am befuddled by a simple `equals` method.

The question given is

> "Given the following array declarations, what does the following print"

and I thought it would be true, false, true however after copy and pasting the code it reveals the answer is false, false, true.

I understand that the `==` only works when they are the same instance of the object but I do not understand why the first on is false. I tried finding the method in the array api but could not find one with the same arguments.

Forgive me if this is obvious, I've been up late the past couple nights studying and am quite jaded on caffeine at the moment.

```
int[] d = { 1, 2, 3 };
int[] b = { 1, 2, 3 };
int[] c = d;
System.out.println(d.equals(b));
System.out.println(d == b);
System.out.println(d == c);
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Basically, array types don't override `equals` to provide value equality... so you end up with the default implementation in Object, which is reference equality.

For value equality in arrays (i.e. equal elements in the same order), use the static methods in the [`Arrays`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html) class.

Comment: +1 for providing hints on how to achieve sequence/value equality (and not because you're Jon Skeet).

Comment: And just to complete the thought, there are several overloads of `Arrays.equals`, as well as an `Arrays.deepEquals(Object,Object)`, which can give you a more "natural" equality.

Comment: Object has an equals method....I knew that I couldn't think, I get it now after a nap. Thank you so much for helping me understand!!

Answer (score 3):

Plain Java arrays (ie, not ArrayList or some such) do not, themselves, implement `equals`, but rather use the implementation in `Object`.  This is basically just an address compare.

(But note that java.util.Arrays implements some static `equals` methods for generic arrays.)

Answer (score 1):

An Array is an Object and it doesn't override Object.equals(), so the standard implementation of Object.equals() applies. `array.equals(something)` is true if and only if `array == something`.

Answer (score 1):

Arrays implicitly extend `Object` class. So, your `equals` method is inherited from there. The default implementation of `equals` method just checks the identity equality, i.e. is the same as `==`.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that the `==` operator only compares for reference equality, so the second and third print statements do what you expect.

The `.equals` method might compare by some other means than reference equality, but that requires the class definition to actually implement that method. If `.equals` is not implemented in the array class, then the runtime will fall back on `Object#equals`, which is the same reference equality that you find with the `==` operator.

In other words, it seems that either there is no `.equals` method in the backing class for arrays, or it is implemented differently than element-by-element comparison.