# When I test my program that hashes password using SecretKeyFactory it always returns passwords are not the same

Tags: java

In my code I try to hash a password using `PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1` instance of `SecretFactory`.
(before that you will see that O generate random salt)

But when I try to test the program in a simple java project with two passwords that are the same it gives me a response that they are not the same. What may be the reason?

```
tatic byte[] salt = new byte[16];
public static String password = "peachy";
public static String newpassword = "peachy";

public static byte []storedpassword;

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    generateSalt();
    System.out.println("salt1:"+salt.toString());
    storedpassword=hash(password,salt);
    System.out.println(storedpassword.toString());
    boolean answer = check(newpassword, storedpassword);
    System.out.println(answer);


}
public static void generateSalt()
{
     Random randomno = new Random();
     randomno.nextBytes(salt);

}

private static byte[] hash(String password, byte[] salt) throws Exception   
{  
    SecretKeyFactory f = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1");
    KeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(password.toCharArray(), salt, 65536, 128);

    return f.generateSecret(spec).getEncoded();

}
public static boolean check(String givenPassword, byte[] storedPassword)
   throws Exception{
        System.out.println("salt2:"+salt.toString());
        byte[] hashOfInput = hash(givenPassword,salt);
        System.out.println(hashOfInput.toString());
        return hashOfInput.equals(storedPassword);
   }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 return Arrays.equals(hashOfInput,storedPassword);
```

You can't compare the `byte[]` using the `.equals()` method, use the code above. The reason why you cannot compare them using the .equals() method is because the `byte[]`'s equals() method tests for reference equality, not logical (every byte is the same) equality. This is because `byte[]` inherits from `Object`, and that is how the `Object` class's `equals()` method is implemented.

For more information, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8392771/how-does-an-arrays-equal-method-work) and the answer by Jon Skeet.

Comment: thank you! By the way just before i read your comment I was reading about comparing byte[] and I realized my mistake!! Thank you!